# How can I add tags and where can I find a list of all tags on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am new to Stack Overflow. What is the best way to add tags to the post?

How can I get the list of all available tags for this forum, preferably in text format? I would like to have it for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is, type which programming language and any specific area in that programming language. On top, right beside Tags you will see all tags. As you type words in tags box, you will get autosuggestion of tags also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small text box under the large field where you write your question - in which you can type tags, and as you type, it will auto-suggest tags for your question, so if you're asking about `Ruby`, just start typing it, and it will show up in a list, along with other suggestions.

For example, on your post, if I want to add the [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) to your post, I just type `tag` and this appears:

[image]
Then I can just select the most relevant tag and go from there.  If I change my mind about a tag, I can click the little `X` on the right-hand side of the tag, and it will disappear.

You can also **view a complete list of tags** on Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/tags:

[image]